# Select inside select not working properly and shows error

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
t_orderPayment with n_id,n_order,n_paytype AND
t_paytype with n_ID , str_desc
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT t_OrderPayment.n_order , 
t_OrderPayment.n_paytype = (select t_paytype.str_desc as n_paytype from t_PayType, t_orderpayment where t_OrderPayment.n_PayType = t_PayType.n_ID)
FROM t_OrderPayment
WHERE (((t_OrderPayment.n_PaymentStatus)<>-7)) ;
```

It returns error

> "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

I tried to set it with MAX and TOP 1 like n_paytype = (select max(t_paytype.str_desc) but shows me error Expr1001
Str.desc have only text values and this could be the reason. May be INNER JOIN can help me somehow?

Comment: Can you please format the code and specify what is the desired result ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Comment: If this query `select t_paytype.str_desc as n_paytype from t_PayType, t_orderpayment where t_OrderPayment.n_PayType = t_PayType.n_ID` returns more than one scalar value, you cannot use it within an assigning sub-select...

Comment: I believe it is Microsoft Access and i open it with Visual Data Manager.
However i manage to sort it out. I finally understood INNER JOIN
Here is the code if anyone need it in the future:
SELECT t_OrderPayment.t_date,n_order,t_Paytype.str_desc as n_PayType

FROM t_OrderPayment
INNER JOIN t_paytype on t_OrderPayment.n_PayType = t_PayType.n_ID
WHERE (((t_OrderPayment.n_PaymentStatus)<>-7)) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've accidentally made a cross join. You don't need a second reference to the `t_OrderPayment` table inside the subquery - try removing that (but leaving the where clause as that's what will link it to the outer query). It looks like the whole subquery could be removed and turned into a join though...

```
SELECT t_OrderPayment.n_order,
       t_paytype.str_desc AS n_paytype
FROM   t_OrderPayment
       INNER JOIN t_PayType
               ON t_OrderPayment.n_PayType = t_PayType.n_ID
WHERE  t_OrderPayment.n_PaymentStatus <> -7;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t_OrderPayment.n_order,
       t_paytype.str_desc AS n_paytype
FROM   t_OrderPayment, t_PayType
WHERE  t_OrderPayment.n_PayType = t_PayType.n_ID AND 
t_OrderPayment.n_PaymentStatus <> -7;